# How to set speed of avplayer of tvos application, based on user clicking the button like 2x,3x

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, tvos

Iam working with AVPlayer of tvos application,making the speed of the avplayer when user clicks button 3x (self.player.rate = 3.0). But rate of playing the video is not changing it is playing at normal rate. is rate property is not work in tvos application. can any help me how to set the speed of the avplayer.

Here is my setup code.

```
func setUpPlayer(videourl:String) {
    playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: URL(string: videourl)!)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    self.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.none
    let av = AVPlayerViewController()
    av.player = player
    av.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1920, height: 1080)
    av.showsPlaybackControls = true
    self.addChildViewController(av)
    self.view.addSubview(av.view)
    if isfromspeed {
        self.player!.rate = 3.0
    }
    player.play()
}
```

Comment: reload the method from which u are playing video. It will work.

Comment: which method i need to reload

Comment: its like you can't change rate in between of playing audio/video. Change rate using rate property and again play your video.

Comment: k i have a button speed when i click on it iam calling method setupvideoplayer() and this is my code

Comment: func setUpPlayer(videourl:String)
    {
        playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: URL(string: videourl)!)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        self.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.none
        let av = AVPlayerViewController()
        av.player = player
        av.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1920, height: 1080)
        av.showsPlaybackControls = true
        self.addChildViewController(av)
        self.view.addSubview(av.view)
        if isfromspeed
        {
            self.player!.rate = 3.0
        }
        player.play()  }

Comment: iam not using avplayerviewcontroller directly. making it as subcontroller for viewcontroller

Comment: is there any option to change the rate of playing video when video is playing

Comment: i am not sure about this thing. Might be someone will tell.

Comment: k thank u for sharing ur knowledge

Comment: Please dont place code in comments - use the question body.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1388846-rate)...

> A value of 0.0 pauses the video, while a value of 1.0 plays the current item at its natural rate. Rates other than 0.0 and 1.0 can be used if the associated player item returns true for the AVPlayerItem properties canPlaySlowForward or canPlayFastForward. Negative rate value ranges are supported if the player item returns true for the canPlayReverse, canPlaySlowReverse, and canPlayFastReverse properties.

You will need to confirm that both the current media and platform supports values other than `0.0` or `1.0`

Comment: self.playerItem.canPlayFastForward is returns false for playeritem

Comment: So therefore setting rate to `3.0` will have no effect.